# how can i use position bottom to animate a div to the top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently am trying to animate the position of a div in a 3 tier structure, the first tier shows only the header, the second the header and excerpt and then the 3rd some additional copy. At the moment I can animate position bottom for both tier 1 and tier 2 but cant seem to figure out how I animate the tier 3 to what would ideally be top:0 which I dont think I can do. Can anyone offer any advice on how this can be achieved?

JS

```
more.on('click', function(e){

  if( body.hasClass('tier1') ){
    body.removeClass('tier1').addClass('tier2');
    wrapper.delay(500).animate({ bottom: wrapper.data('tier2') }, 400, function(){
      //show close
      close.show();
    });

  } else if ( body.hasClass('tier2') ){
    body.removeClass('tier2').addClass('tier3');
    wrapper.delay(1500).animate({ bottom: '300' }, 500, function(){ // show be top of window
      // hide read more
      more.hide();

      // hide .excerpt + show .upper
      excerpt.fadeOut(function(){
        upper.fadeIn();
      });
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Link to current build: http://bit.ly/IA65Mb

Kyle

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow.  After you click the "+" symbol 2 times, you want the box to animate to the top of the page?

Comment: yeah i want the box to scale the height of the window and sit fixed to the top. right now if you where to change #wrapper from bottom: to top:0 youll see the effect i want to produce

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/d3eLE/6/
HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
        <a id="me">Click me</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ff0;
}

#me {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#me").click(function(){
    $("#wrap").animate({
        bottom: ( $(window).height() - $("#wrap").height() )
    }, 2000);

 });
```

Instead of using bottom, you could make use of top.

```
$("#wrap").removeAttr("bottom").animate({
    top: 0
}, 2000);
```

Comment: this doesnt achieve what i need, i want the div to sit where it would if it had position top:0 no matter what height the window is. using bottom position for the other 2 tiers im not sure how this can be achieved?

Comment: hey thanks for this, ideally i could really do with using position top because i resize the page the content disappears due to the nature of using bottom, any ideas? if i change to top:0 for tier 3 this works but the animation doesnt and clicking to move to tier 2 breaks down?